# problems with setting parameters query objects

Tags: google-apps-script

Why `app.getElementById('myTextBox').setValue('default')` work in `showDialog()` but didnt work in `respondToSubmit(e)`?

```
function showDialog() {
  var app = UiApp.createApplication();
  var panel = app.createVerticalPanel();

  var textBox = app.createTextBox();
  textBox.setName('myTextBox').setId('myTextBox');
  app.getElementById('myTextBox').setValue('default');

  var button = app.createButton(Modify');
  panel.add(textBox);
  panel.add(button);

  var clickHandler = app.createServerClickHandler("respondToSubmit");
  button.addClickHandler(clickHandler);
  clickHandler.addCallbackElement(panel);

  app.add(panel);
  var doc = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  doc.show(app);
}

function respondToSubmit(e) {
  var app = UiApp.getActiveApplication();
  app.getElementById('myTextBox').setText('Modifed');
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add

```
return app;
```

at the end of your respondToSubmit function

Comment: Thanks Srik, this was so obvious I didn't see it :-)

Answer (score 0):

in one case you use setText(), in the other you use setValue() ... didn't you notice ?

Also, when you are in the same function where you create an element you don't need to use `getElementById()` you can just use `textBox.setValue()` since textBox is the variable that holds the element- the `getElementById` is only used to recall an element from another function.

Comment: i know) i do it for testing `getElementById()` in different conditions)